# Endless deadlock situation on mySQL innoDB

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, database-deadlocks

Here is an issue which I encountered recently in my MySQLdb 5.7 (with innoDB engine) hosted in a Virtual Machine in my Google Cloud Platform account. 
Suddenly,  my DB came to a state where every transaction (such as logins) on a specific table named 'users' failed (endless timeout).
I took this error: `pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'`

Well, basically I try to find out if there is an automated recovery from this circled situation. I read in MySQL's site that by default is performed a rollback to last transaction, but why did't happen this in my situation? After a long time remaining in this situation I had to restart the MySQL server.

I need some directions on how to investigate it or take action for not facing it up again because it's a live database with customers.

Comment: Another transaction is holding a lock on the table/row. 
Try to identify this transaction with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` or/and `select * from information_schema.innodb_lock_waits;` and/or  `select * from information_schema.innodb_locks;`. Probably a backup running?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I think these queries show results only when a deadlock occurs, right? If i want to see what exactly happened then, how can i do this searching in error logs of Google Cloud Platform? Because, i didn't find a record with 'deadlock' keyword, perhaps there is another way to find out? Is there any way for auto recovery from this situation?

Comment: Could you share which errors you are seeing for your VM in Google Cloud Platform Logging?

Comment: Hi! I m just seeking for errors related to deadlocks or something like that. I just want to identify what caused this endless deadlock.

Comment: Hello John, has this been solved for you? 
If not: according to the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) a rollback takes place if either the "innodb_deadlock_detect" configuration option is set (which it is by default) or, otherwise, if "innodb_deadlock_detect" is not set and the value defined with option "innodb_lock_wait_timeout" (a number of seconds) has been exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's InnoDB Engine sports row-level locking, which can lead to deadlocks even when your code is inserting or updating a single row (specially if there are several indexes on the table being updated). Your best bet is to design the code around this in order to retry a transaction if it fails due to a deadlock. Some useful info about MySQL deadlock diagnose and possible workarounds is available in [MySQL Official Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)

Comment: I tried to set locks in my stored procedures as this suggests: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html,  but i take the message "locks are not allowed in stored procedures". Do you know what can cause an endless deadlock? Because i didn't find something in the internet for this... Everywhere says that rollbacks are performed automatically, but this why did't happened in my situation? How can i figure it out?

Comment: Could you share the code or SQL statements for your stored procedures in order to investigate further ? Thanks

Comment: Above is the store procedure for the login process, in which we detect the endless deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the stored procedure for the login process in which we detect the endless deadlock.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `login`(
    in email1 varchar(45), 
    in password1 varchar(256),
    in lastlogin datetime, 
    out s INT(1)
    )
    BEGIN
    DECLARE p INT(11);
    DECLARE counter TINYINT;

      IF EXISTS (select * from user where user.email = email1 AND user.password = password1 AND user.locked = 0 AND user.inactive = 0) THEN
          SELECT id INTO p FROM user WHERE user.email = email1;
          SELECT user.id, user.id_user_roles, user.id_user_settings, user.first_name, user.last_name, UserRoles.description
          FROM user
          LEFT JOIN UserRoles
          ON user.id_user_roles = UserRoles.id_user_roles WHERE user.id = p;
          UPDATE user SET last_login = lastlogin WHERE user.id = p;
          INSERT INTO login_info (id_user, timestamp)
          VALUES (p, lastlogin);
          SET s = 1; 
      ELSE
          SELECT login_error_times INTO counter FROM user WHERE email = email1;
          IF (counter < 3) THEN
             SET counter = counter + 1;
             UPDATE user
             SET login_error_times = counter
             WHERE user.email = email1;
             SET s = 0; 
          ELSE
             UPDATE user
             SET locked = 1
             WHERE user.email = email1;
             SET s = 2;
          END IF;   
      END IF;
    END
```